# dev-certs generate cert with no root

Tags: .net, https, kestrel

My OS is ubuntu 18.04

With no sudo doesnt work

```
$ dotnet dev-certs https
There was an error saving the HTTPS developer certificate to the current user personal certificate store.
```

if i use

```
$ sudo dotnet dev-certs https
```

Ok, but only run a mvc program without sudo i get

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
```

Comment: You probably used `sudo` the first time you generated the certificate so the user's folders belonged to the `root` user. Changing owner permission (`chmod -R`) for the `.dotnet` folder and its content would probably have helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem.
I delete folders .aspnet .dotnet and .nuget
Re run dotnet dev-certs https

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on your accepted answer, but it fixed this issue for me after half a day of searching. I'll just describe what the problem looked like for me (for documentation sake). I recently installed .NET7 for one of our recently upgraded projects, and I got the dev-certs notification upon running the app. I'm on a Mac 2021 with Apple Silicon, if it matters.

```
dotnet dev-certs https (works)

dotnet dev-certs https --trust (works)

dotnet dev-certs https --check
No valid certificate found.
```

In the end, I ran it as you described, and made sure to delete all 'localhost' certificates in my Keychain Access

```
rm -rf ~/.dotnet
rm -rf ~/.aspnet
rm -rf ~/.nuget
```

Rerunning the three `dotnet dev-certs` commands as described fixed the issue.

Comment: I think the issue was that somehow my ~/.aspnet folder got created with sudo rights. Which was the real culprit to this. Thank you so much for your response here! After removing all folders with sudo rights, then running the dev-certs commands without sudo rights, everything worked.